# Howto set a global property in complete method of subscriber ngrx angular

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, subscriber

I have a global property  `loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = false;`
I have a method with an observable , where I set the loadingIndicatorsearchVisible to show or no a load panel.

```
search(){
    this.loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = true;
    this.subscriptionQuickSearch$ =
    this.entiteSearchService.getQuickSearch()
    .subscribe(
      {
        next: (sucess) => {
                     this.entitieSearchActifsDataSource = this.entiteSearchService.entitieSearchActifsDataSource;

                    },
          error:(error) =>  {
                    this.loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = false;
                    },
          complete() {
                this.loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = false;
          }
      })
```

It´s working fine, but I want  when the subscriber end , in the complete method set loadingIndicatorsearchVisible=false, to hide the load panel.
But I have this kind of error:

```
Property 'loadingIndicatorsearchVisible' does not exist on type 'Partial<Observer<boolean>>
```

Why I cant use loadingIndicatorsearchVisible in the complete method?

Best regards

Comment: Note this is not ngrx, but is rxjs related

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined your complete callback correctly, it should be:

```
complete: () => {
  this.loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wlf, It´s working. I'm so distracted. I have also another solution with pipe and finalize, like this guarantees it will be called on error, complete, and unsubscription.this.entiteSearchService.getQuickSearch()
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            //This guarantees it will be called on error, complete, and unsubscription
            this.loadingIndicatorsearchVisible = false;
          })
        ).subscribe ...

Comment: A pipe solution is better IMO as its more idiomatic. You might want to accept this answer too.